# Every time I source my R script it leaks a db connection

Tags: r, rmysql, r-dbi, connection-leaks

I cannot paste the entire script here, but I am explaining the situation. If you have ever got leaked DB connections then you would be knowing what I am talking about.

I have an R script file that has many functions (around 50) that use db connections using the `DBI` & `RMySQL` R packages. I have consolidated all DB access through 4 or 5 functions. I use `on.exit(dbDisconnect(db))` in every single function where a `dbConnect` is used.

I discovered that just on loading this script using `source("dbscripts.R")`  causes one DB connection to leak.  I see this when I run the command

```
dbListConnections(MySQL())
```

> [[1]]
>   MySQLConnection:0,607>
>
> [[2]]
>   MySQLConnection:0,608>
>
> [[3]]
>   MySQLConnection:0,609>
>
> [[4]]
>   MySQLConnection:0,610>

I see **one more DB connection added** to the list everytime. This quickly reaches to 16 and my script stops working.

The problem is, I am unable to find out which line of code is causing the leak.
I have checked each `dbConnect` line in the code. All of them are within functions and no `dbConnect` happens outside in the main code.

So, why is the connection leak occurring?

Comment: it seems like you've created a connection that you haven't closed. I don't know of anyway to find it other than making a list of all of the connections you've made and matching them against all of your `on.exit`s. I feel your pain. I had a similar problem this week. took me an hour to find the one I missed.

Comment: I am intrigued how even without running any function could any `dbConnect` run. I can understand if any `DbConnect` line was sitting outside in the main body of the code.

Comment: Do you ever use `on.exit` for something else? The default mode of `on.exit` is quizzically to over-write the list of functions; if yes, then using `on.exit(..., add=TRUE)` should help.

Comment: Short of that, unfortunately this question is completely unreproducible. I'm gathering that it's a not-small file, so posting it would be cluttering (if even possible, if private). If there is literally no code outside of your function declaration blocks, then it is really a mystery that `source`ing alone would cause this. I often have ancillary code-blocks (examples, backup code) within `if (FALSE) { ... }` blocks to prevent this kind of mistake (while keeping the code available for manual sourcing), but this is not infallible.

Comment: How do I make a list of connections @Benjamin? Because I am not opening any connection in the main body of the R script? All of the `dbConnect` lines are inside function bodies and I am not yet executing any function.

Comment: I have a very 'high tech' process of opening each file and doing a search for `dbConnect`, and writing down each object I find. then I search for `dbDisconnect` and cross out every object I've closed. I also look for instances for `dbConnect` that I haven't assigned to an object. I approach the entire process with the assumption that I've done something I didn't intend to do.

Comment: Anyone else wanting to suggest a method. I can't find any leaks manually.